# How do you query for a list of all repositories that are available in a WORKSPACE?

Tags: bazel

Is it possible to use `bazel query` to get a list of all remote repositories (e.x. @com_google_protobuf) that are available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of any way to get exactly this, however you can get an overapproximation by querying the synthetic `//external` package. It contains one target for every external repository. However, it contains some other targets by default.

Example:

```
$ cat WORKSPACE
local_repository(name = "a", path = "a")
maven_jar(name = "b", artifact = "com.google.guava:guava:19.0")

$ bazel query //external:all
//external:local_jdk
//external:local_config_xcode
//external:local_config_cc
//external:jre-default
//external:jre
//external:jni_md_header-linux
//external:jni_md_header-freebsd
//external:jni_md_header-darwin
//external:jni_header
//external:jdk-default
//external:jdk
//external:javac
//external:java
//external:jar
//external:has_androidsdk
//external:extdir
//external:extclasspath
//external:cc_toolchain
//external:bootclasspath
//external:bazel_tools
//external:bazel_j2objc
//external:b
//external:android_sdk_for_testing
//external:android_ndk_for_testing
//external:android/sdk
//external:android/dx_jar_import
//external:android/crosstool
//external:a
```

Note that `//external:a` and `//external:b` appear in the results.

Comment: To complete Adam answer: there is no good way to do this at the moment, the best estimation is querying //external:*. Be careful that it will trigger a download of all repositories.

Alternatively you could write a repository rule that write to a a files the list of repositories using native.existing_rules().

Comment: With`bazel query //external:all` the output was entirely empty on Bazel 6.1.1. Use `*` or `all-targets` instead of `all`!